# AngularJS Directives: Using ng-switch breaks transclusion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive, ng-switch

I have created a directive for displaying large amounts of data in a tree structure.  When an element is collapsed, its content is hidden using the ng-show command.

Here is a heavily simplified version [on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mRXmqN?p=preview).

The directive is called collapsible-test, and is used as so:

```
<div collapsible-test>
    <p>Here is some content....</p>
    <div collapsible-test>
        <p>Here is some more content....</p>
        <div collapsible-test>
            <p>Here is even more content....</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The part of the directive template that controls the collapsing looks like this:

```
<div ng-show="!collapsed" class="panel-body">
    <div ng-transclude></div>
</div>
```

This all works fine, however I will need to use it for **hundreds** of nested elements using ng-repeat.  This causes the page to take 10-15 seconds to load, and then there are also great delays when expanding and collapsing the elements.

I tried to alleviate this by replacing the ng-show directive with ng-switch. (I'll use ng-if when I update angular at a later date.)  This approach does not work, because using the transclude service on DOM elements that are not yet present generates an error.

```
<div ng-switch="collapsed">
    <div ng-switch-when="false" class="panel-body">
        <div ng-transclude></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I thought I might have to recompile every time I change the 'collapse' state, but I can't understand how to make it work.

Or, perhaps there is a better way to solve my problem that I haven't thought of yet.

**EDIT:**

OverZealous answered my question perfectly, thanks!  This is just an update for those who try to dosomething similar.  This method will only work outside of an ng-repeat loop.  It appears that ng-if converts the DOM code into a comment when it fails the test.  Therefore, ng-repeat will do nothing but repeat the comment (or something like that).  So ng-if and ng-switch are still not foolproof, but they are fine you don't require ng-repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can upgrade to Angular.js 1.1.5 (a prerelease) or 1.2.0-rc2 (a release candidate), you can use `ng-if` to make this work.

[Example Plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/kPhxEp?p=preview)

Template:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div ng-if="!collapsed" ng-transclude></div>
</div>
```

What I did is changed the `ng-show` to `ng-if`, and moved it directly onto the `ng-transclude` element.  This appears to work, and if you look at the DOM in your developer tools, you can see that all descendent nodes are *removed* when the parent is collapsed.

Note that all child elements are rebuilt when a parent is expanded, so unless you save the collapsed state somewhere, the child nodes are re-created in the collapsed state.  This may be confusing for your users.

---

**If you can't upgrade to the latest release**

You can use the `ngIf` provided by Angular UI, which should work exactly the same:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngIf.js